# How do you name your projects?

Tags: naming

At work we're having issues with different people wanting/suggesting different names for a new project. It's changed 4 times in the last 2 days.

What processes do people go through when naming internal projects? How do you work as a team to come to a conclusion for a project name?

To make this a little clearer, the question is *HOW* do you name your projects, not *what* do you name them. I'm more on about a process so we don't get the 3/4 managers involved spending the next 4 weeks changing the name of the project every 4 hours

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026/naming-products

Comment: this is more "resolving conflicts within the team about naming"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is the team choosing the name. Don't you have a manager? That's how organizations are supposed to work: if one level can't achieve the goal in a timely manner, escalate it up to the next level.

What a colossal waste of time!

Comment: Escalating to management may be OK with for deciding on a name, but when it comes to technical decisions it's an awful idea.  Managers almost always know less about the technical merits of a question than the developers do.  Managers are the last people you want making technical decisions.

Comment: there are 3 managers that are involved in the project, it's them who're arguing :D and trying to consult us along the way... *headwalls*

Comment: @Chris, if the techs can't make a decision collectively, you need to present your cases to management and let them decide (it'll probably be the choice of their most trusted team member). You inform them of the merits and accept their decision. If it was clear-cut, the techs wouldn't be arguing.

Comment: @Martin, it sounds like the project therefore belongs to *their* manager and it should still be escalated.

Comment: @Pax: If it's not clear cut, how do you expect a manager, who knows less about the problem than the developers, to make the correct decision?  If the developers can't decide among themselves, you hired the wrong developers.

See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/12/04.html (last paragraph)

Comment: We already know the devs can't do it, 3 days wasted already. And the manager doesn't need to know, just select the choice of the most trusted dev - it doesn't matter what the decision is as long as there's a decision and the devs can get back to doing what they're paid for. Just break the logjam.

Comment: And sacking the developers is going to get you nowhere fast - yes, they may be clowns but the cost of replacing them in the short term is bound to be high.

Answer (score 4):

We name them after asimov characters.

The blackjack client was Hari.

Comment: I try and name everything I can after Asimov characters too!

Comment: Brilliant! I'll be doing this from now on.

Comment: Ooh, I've seen Gibson characters done: Molly, Finn, Blackwell and Wintermute

Answer (score 3):

Have everyone put their suggestions in a hat, and pull a name at random. Does it really matter?

Answer (score 3):

1. Have the team make many suggestions.
2. Have management and Legal weed out the problematic names.
3. Have the team vote on the remaining names.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of all potential names, each person only gets to make one name suggestion. Have everyone vote on the names. Each person can vote only once, and not for their own name.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how saddled with a name you will be.
For instance if its a .Net project, you will be quite stuck with the name you choose, in which case the projects usually get a really boring naming, even if the site has a nice naming.

In other technologies where there is no "manifest" to the code, named as a project, and moving the code to a new folder name is the "project" then witty names seems to be great fun.

Answer (score 0):

One company I was with named all their projects according to vacation city names.  So we had Paris, Athens, etc.  I've also used greek gods and constellations.  There wasn't much of a process to it, just whatever the development team thought was cool.  Though there was an instance where we allowed our beta partner at the time to pick the name of the project - they had a whole contest and everything.

Another project I was on had four phases:
Red, Green, Blue, and 4

Gotta love that.

Comment: You mean the project with the Beta partner?  Yeah, but the Beta partner was involved from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use letters to indicate versions of your product, and have team members vote on words that start with the letters.

We've had one project that was named Ambition, Benevolence, Charisma, etc.

I like to use [Instant Runoff Voting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_runoff_voting) for this.

I've also found that having new team members suggest names helps them feel ownership for the project.

Answer (score 0):

For my personal projects I name them after Revolutionary War battles (e.g. Lexington, Concord, Saratoga, Ticonderoga).  I'm also fond of using names from Greek mythology since I'm a big fan of that :)

Another personal project was named Rushmore (as in Mt. Rushmore).  IMO it all depends on what you fancy and whether or not the project name is going to be publicly visible.  If it's not, then name it whatever you want (the more mysterious the better if you ask me!) but if it will be public then choose something that doesn't sound ridiculous or will make people go "Huh?".  `Project Fig Newton` or `Project Twinkie` might sound funny to a group of devs, but how will it sound to customers?

Comment: Why the vote down?  Somebody name their project Fig Newton or Twinkie and took offense?  Or just not a fan of mountains/greek mythology/american revolution?

Comment: I hope that RushMore wasn't a organizer/diary type of application ;)

Answer (score 0):

Name your projects in a way that helps developers know what they are when you put the under source control. Outside of your current source control it doesn't matter what people call it.

Try to pick a naming convention that stays the same it will help organize things in your source control and try to stay away from initials and abbreviations because once all the DEVs on that project leave no one will know what the project is.

Try sticking to names like:
customerA Website
customerB WinApp

Answer (score 0):

One place I worked used mountains for the framework, and ski resorts for the client; Another used tube stations. In both cases they were internal names that didn't have a fixed version number (as marketing had a habit of changing that)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen architects choose, CTOs mandate, dev teams rota, and a reward for some arbitrary competition but ultimately it comes down to one man with one vote. You can democratise that any way you want, but whatever you do just make sure it's inoffensive and you stick to it.

Fwiw, my favourite system has been the architect who chose Judge Dredd characters. :D

Answer (score 0):

For personal projects I sometimes use names of big cities, like New York, Berlin, Tokyo etc.
It' both convenient since I feel the project isn't bound to a specific technology or function and can involve into whatever it might be, while at the same time it can be a bit difficult remembering if it was Tokyo or Oslo which was doing "that" cool thing..

At work we have a tradition for more simple and descriptive names. For instance an application that uploads files according to a schedule is called ScheduledFileUploader. And then there's FileOrganizer, MailSender, DiskSpaceMonitor et.c..

Answer (score 0):

you mean a code name? since its gonna stick only in the minds of internal employees, we usually named it the first thing we thought of and we never put it up for discussion, one project we had named "Dough" seriously! :) and it worked like magic, anything works

Answer (score 0):

My big brother Mikael has been called to some *firefighting* in very late projects which...he chose some movie titles

- **Save Willy** - *a bloated java project*
- **Harry Potter** - *a architectural disaster java project*

Answer (score 0):

- Female names (everybody likes a nice name, specially if it brings nice memories)
- Animals (everybody likes animals)

We usually agree very fast on this one, no problems there. After we have named something, for example, "chipmunk", the jokes and funny pictures start to arrive (everybody likes making up jokes :)

But really, I don't think it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Name your projects after [constellations](http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~dolan/constellations/constellation_list.html). There are plenty to choose from, most sound cool. Also when you get to the Aries project, you can tell people that you're [checking the cell structure and the cell structure has been checked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeper_(film)).

Answer (score 0):

With great care and a lot of personal pain.  I quite frankly obsess about my personal project names.  Even to the point that I will spend hours thinking about the name of a particular type or DLL.

Sadly this is not a joke.

Comment: ??? Dear anonymous person, why would you vote down a answer to a subjective question that is on topic?

Answer (score 0):

No project names, just version numbers.

Everybody knows that if you released "MyBlaPro 4" you are working on "MyBlaPro 5" and it is going to be out in 1-2 years (your company history can offer a hint on the length of your dev. cycles).
The big secret is not that you are working on the next version, but when it is out.

Code names confuse not only outsiders (think Avalon/WPF, Longhorn/XP/2000/Vista/7) but also insiders. You can sometimes hear discussions like this "no, we added X in Zimfandel, before Cabernet" "no, you are wrong, Cabernet was 5, Zimfandel was 6, but X was added in Merlot"

Add to the mess the half-outsiders. Think localization companies that have to reuse memory translations between versions ("for Rainier we should use the memory from Shasta, or from Whitney?").